# Matlab:How to LOWER signal to noise of audio

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, signal-processing, noise

I have some code that block processes the xcorr command with parallel computing too. I want to test how robust cross correlation is with data that has lower S/N.

The only problem is I don't quite know how to apply this. I have an audio file with animal calls. It is mostly noise with intermittent calls. all the calls have different S/N. If you look at the Short Term Fourier Transform spectrogram of the animal call, you will see a blob with a distribution of different intensities.

[image: spectrogram]

I want to lower the S/N of these calls so that the shape of the distribution of intensities is still the same, it's just that they are smaller in intensity.

To successfully lower the S/N of the audio, I'm assuming I don't want to change the background noise values either, so only the calls themselves are lowering in amplitude but not the noise.

I don't quite know how I can program this, can I get some help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely just add extra noise to the whole sample, this is common when testing robustness: if your original sample has say 50 units** of signal and 50 units of noise (SNR of 50/50) then adding say 100 units of noise will lead to a SNR or 50/150, which is lower.

**subject to discussion of what constitutes a unit - power vs voltage, dBs or whatever, it's just for the sake of an example.

If it's important what type of noise you add then perhaps you could copy some from the sections without samples in - doing this manually is usually efficient enough when creating test cases. Alternatively `rand` will give you random numbers and `rng` will let you control the distribution.

An alternative method might be to apply a compression function to the spectrograph and then apply the inverse transform to bring it back to the time domain. Beware of using modified versions of your training data to test the algorithm, if you have sufficient data you'd be best to reserve some for testing.

Comment: I happened to see this link which somewhat does what you say (although a bit more specific than simply adding noise):
http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2010/02/generating-a-signal-waveform-with-required-snr-in-matlab-2/ 

I have run the code, which outputs the noise, the new signal, and the SNR (of 5 in the example). But if you plug the new signal and noise into matlabs snr(...) command, you get a different snr value. Is there a reason for this?
The measuredSNR output variable is 4.9968 but if you enter: snr(scaledSignal,noise) this will give you 6.2034

Comment: This all depends on how you measure signals and noise. There are various ways of doing it, no standard, and the results will differ depending on the method. In the linked article they offer two methods based on `norm` and `var`, matlab's `snr` also offers various methods - see `doc snr` for a list. In the linked article they link to another about some of these methods, that's worth a read too.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a sound file editor (plus a file full of noise of your desired distribution and type), first turn down the level of the original file until the signal is at your desired lower level, then mix in the noise file to bring the noise back up to the original level (by setting the appropriate mixer parameters).  The resulting mix will have a lower S/N.

Comment: This method will avoid the potential clipping problem that my prior answer could produce.